# Как работают mask&(1<<ch)) битовые операции

Tags: c, битовые-операции

Объясните пожалуйста, по какому принципу работает условие `if(mask&(1<<ch))` в следующей программе:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
int main(void)
{
    int n,mask,maxmask,q,ch,k;
    FILE *pfile;
    pfile=fopen("C:/MinGW/progi/elem.txt","r");
    if(pfile==NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found\n");
            return -1;
    }
    while(fscanf(pfile,"%d",&n)==1)
    {
        ch=n;
    }
    maxmask=1<<ch;
    for(mask=0; mask!=maxmask; ++mask)
    {
        for(q=0; q<ch; q++)
            if(mask&(1<<q))
                printf("%d ", q+1);

        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверка, установлен ли q-й бит.

Смотрите, например, мы хотим проверить, установлен ли 5-й бит в 00100100 (беру только 8 бит).

Сначала создаем маску с 1 в пятой позиции:

```
1 << 5:

00000001 - исходная 1
00100000 - после сдвига <<5
```

Теперь побитовая операция & оставит 1 только в тех позициях, где в обоих числах стоит 1. А в сделанной нами маске она только в одном месте - на 5 позиции (считая с нулевой). Итак:

```
00100100 & 00100000 = 00100000
```

Значение ненулевое - значит, в исходном значении эта единица установлена.